# react script start: reference error in file without using that reference

Tags: javascript, reactjs, build, react-scripts

Well after starting up a project today - I get the following error when I run `npm run start`

```
> react-scripts start

Starting the development server...

Failed to compile.

./src/index.css (./node_modules/css-loader??ref--6-oneOf-3-1!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??postcss!./src/index.css)
ReferenceError: EntryViewOpenableBase is not defined
```

Which seems really a strange error, since I haven't touched index.css. The contents of index.css are:

```
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", "Roboto", "Oxygen",
    "Ubuntu", "Cantarell", "Fira Sans", "Droid Sans", "Helvetica Neue",
    sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}

code {
  font-family: source-code-pro, Menlo, Monaco, Consolas, "Courier New",
    monospace;
}
```

So what can cause this error? And more importantly, how can I debug this?

Comment: Did you try to re-run npm-install?

First remove all of the node_modules first

Comment: @ErtanKara is there no cleaner method than nuking dependencies? As reinstalling requires downloading which requires me to authorize everything and check if the download doesn't contain malicious code.

Comment: As far as I know, there isn't. And it looks like it's very likely that your node_modules contains errors, or some code is missing.